# Facebook jssdk customizes the shared feed interface. Why don't the parameters of picture work?

Tags: facebook, dialog, share, customization, feed

According to the official Facebook document,url：https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

But the parameters in the "Deprecated Parameters" column below do not work.
Is the interface function turned off?
I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

```
   FB.ui(
     {
       method: 'feed',
       name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
       redirect_uri:location.href,
       link: location.href,
       picture: 'https://pic3.zhimg.com/80/37e17fa3d5d60f9e8bcba3bdc7e7dc06_hd.jpg',
       caption: 'Reference Documentation',
       description: 'tDialogs provide a simple.',
       message: 'tFacebook Dialogs are easy!'
     },
     function(response) {
       if (response && response.post_id) {
        console.log(response)
         alert('Post was published.');
       } else {
         alert('Post was not published.');
       }
     }
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the parameters in the "Deprecated Parameters" column below do not work.

That is why they are in the deprecated section (deprecated means "old" or "gone"), they don´t work anymore since a very long time. You have to provide that data with Open Graph tags in the source of the shared URLs.

More information about Open Graph tags: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#markup